# Is there a way to remove category-product slug from url in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

does anyone have an easy solution to remove the "product-category" slug in my urls?

For examples I want:
[www.website.com/product-category/table](http://www.website.com/product-category/table)

to be
[www.website.com/table](http://www.website.com/table)

I've tried:
Settings -> Permalinks -> Remove productcategory base. But that doesn't work.

I prefer not to use any plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily by adding some custom code to your WordPress theme's functions.php file. This solution involves using a custom rewrite rule to achieve the desired URL structure.

```
function custom_rewrite_rules() {
add_rewrite_rule(
    '(.+?)/?$',
    'index.php?product_cat=$matches[1]',
    'top'
);
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rules', 10, 0);

function change_product_cat_link($termlink, $term, $taxonomy) {
if ($taxonomy == 'product_cat') {
    $termlink = str_replace('/product-category/', '/', $termlink);
}
return $termlink;
 }
 add_filter('term_link', 'change_product_cat_link', 10, 3);
```

This code adds a custom rewrite rule to map the new URLs to the correct product categories and changes the links generated for product categories.

**Note:**
After adding code to ensure the changes take effect, you need to flush your permalinks. To do this, go to "Settings" > "Permalinks" in your WordPress dashboard and simply click the "Save Changes" button without making any modifications. This will refresh your site's permalink structure.